# Get indices of all elements with a certain class relative to parent element

Tags: jquery

Is there a one-liner for getting the index of all occurrences of an HTML element inside another element? Like this:

```
<div id="Table"> //table
    <div> //table row
        <div class="string-cell"></div>
        <div class="date-cell"></div>
        <div class="bool-cell"></div>
        <div class="date-cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tableid = "#Table";

    //Select all date cells and get their indices
    var datecellindices = $(tableid).????? //Should be 1 & 3
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) each element to its index, use [get](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) to convert the jquery result set into an array, and I [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them together into a string.

```
$(tableid).children('.date-cell').map(function(){ return $(this).index() }).get().join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.map` for that:

```js
ar = $('#Table div div').map(function(i, el) { if ($(this).hasClass('date-cell')) {  return i; } return null;})

ar.each(
  function(i, val) { 
    console.log(val)
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Table"> //table
    <div> //table row
        <div class="string-cell"></div>
        <div class="date-cell"></div>
        <div class="bool-cell"></div>
        <div class="date-cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```